# Coulomb matrix element in Quasi-2D bilayer system

Tags: condensed-matter, field-theory

In the paper "Electron-hole pairing of Fermi-arc surface states in a Weyl semimetal bilayer" ([arxiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.08612.pdf)) the authors derive an interlayer Coulomb matrix element as (Appendix A).

\begin{align}
V_{\mathbf q, \mathbf k, \mathbf k'} &= \int dz \int dz' V_{\mathbf q}(z-z')\rho^{(+)}_{\mathbf{k+q,k}}(z)\rho^{(-)}_{\mathbf{k+q,k}}(z'-t)\\
\rho^{(\pm)}_{\mathbf{k+q,k}}(z) &= \int dx \int dy e^{i \mathbf{q \cdot r}} {\Psi_{\mathbf{k+q}}^{(\pm)}}^{*}(r)\Psi_{\mathbf{k}}^{(\pm)}(r) \propto \Theta(\mp z)
\end{align}
Here $\pm$ refers to the surface with normal direction $\pm {\hat z}$. $\Theta$ is the Heaviside step function. $V_{\mathbf q}(z - z')$ is the quasi-2D coulomb potential given by
$$
V_{\mathbf q}(z - z') = \frac{2\pi e^{-q(z-z')}}{q}
$$

I don't understand why in the equation for $V_{\mathbf q, \mathbf k, \mathbf k'}$, $V_{\mathbf q}(z-z')$ is used instead of $V_{\mathbf q}(z-z' +t)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the term of $V_{q}(z - z')$ represents the interaction between electrons at $z$ and $z'$, you should not change the parameter of $V_{q}$.

In the Appendix, $\rho^{(-)}$ is corresponds to the charge density without the spacer,  $\rho_{t=0}^{(-)}$. However, because of the spacer whose thickness is $t$, the charge density is shifted as $\rho_{t}^{(-)}(z') = \rho_{t=0}^{(-)}(z'-t)$. This is why you should use $\rho^{(-)}(z'-t)$ instead of $\rho^{(-)}(z').$